# Is there a list of valid options for spark DataFrameReaders and DataFrameWriters?

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a list of valid options for DataFrameReaders and DataFrameWriters?  I'm writing an application that will enable users to set these via yaml configuration and would like to document the options that are available for each of the drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is such list but it is created per source, here are some examples:

[JSON](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html) [CSV](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html) [JDBC](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) - There also other sources on the list in left tab

Scroll down to "Data Source Option" and you will find options with descriptions. If its marked as read/write it means that it applies for both reader and writer